# Send an email with mailx through ssh in a bash script with variables

Tags: bash, shell, email, ssh, mailx

I'm struggling hard to send an email through ssh with mailx. Here's the use case. I'm writing a small deployment script and want to send a custom email at the end. Since our dev machines can't send email directly, I thought of using the integration machine through ssh to do the job. In the script, the recipients, subject and email content are all stored in variables. The content is written in Markdown because it's committed in the project as a changelog.

Here's the command I tried :

```
ssh user@host "echo -e ${CHANGELOG_CONTENT} | mailx -s \"${PROJECT_NAME} - ${TARGET_VERSION} - ${RELEASE_DATE}\" ${CHANGELOG_RECIPIENTS}"
```

I tried several variants before this one, but no luck. This version gives me this error :

```
bash: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

Here's an example of the command with variables replaced by their content (hand-made) :

```
ssh user@host "echo -e Version 1.2\n\n- branch-1 : [gitlab link](http://gitlab.example.com/project-alpha/commits/branch-1)\n\n | mailx -s "Project Alpha - 1.2 - 2015-26-05 13:10" me@example.com you@example.com"
```

I'm pretty sure my errors come from bad escaping/quoting, but since I'm nesting commands with SSH I can't find the proper combination.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can feed a whole script to the stdin of remote `/bin/sh` on the fly using heredocs:

```
ssh user@host /bin/sh <<EOF
mailx -s "${PROJECT_NAME} - ${TARGET_VERSION} - ${RELEASE_DATE}" ${CHANGELOG_RECIPIENTS} <<'END_OF_MAIL_BODY'
${CHANGELOG_CONTENT}
END_OF_MAIL_BODY
EOF
```

Note that it will fail if `$CHANGELOG_CONTENT` contains a line beginning with `END_OF_MAIL_BODY`.

Btw I prefer to use `sendmail`.  It allows better control over sending mails.

```
ssh user@host /bin/sh <<EOF
sendmail -t <<'END_OF_MAIL_HEADER_AND_BODY'
From: ${CHANGELOG_SENDER}
Subject: ${PROJECT_NAME} - ${TARGET_VERSION} - ${RELEASE_DATE}
Bcc: ${CHANGELOG_RECIPIENTS}

${CHANGELOG_CONTENT}
END_OF_MAIL_HEADER_AND_BODY
EOF
```